# ASP.Net c# - Kendo Grid - ValueObject with UIHint <- needs to be dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, kendo-ui

I'm somewhat new to the land of ASP.Net, C# and Kendo.

I need something to use instead of `UIHint("someEditorTemplate")` to take dynamic values.  Our use of these UIHints is mostly to do a KendoDropDown to show a select to populate a field on a form.

The app I'm working on has KendoGrids that specify View Objects:

```
<%
        Html.Kendo().Grid<NoiNlsConsignmentVO>()
           .Name("grdSubSpecies")
           .ToolBar(...)
           .DataSource(ds => ds
                   ...
                   .Read(r => r.Action("GridSelectSubSpecies", "RefData").Data("getSelectedSpecies"))
           ...
           .Editable(e => e.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp))
           .Render() %>
```

And the NoiNlsConsignmentVO is as follows.  Due the Editable attribute on the Grid, a Dialog pops up allowing one to create / edit the fields specified in the VO.

```
namespace Daff.Lae.TraceCommon.ValueObjects
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class NoiNlsConsignmentVO: BaseTraceVO
    {
        [DataMember, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Int32 NoiId { get; set; }

        [DataMember, Required, Display(Name = "Breed", Order = 1)]
        public String BreedCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember, Display(Name = "Description")]
        public String Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember, UIHint("NlsSubSpecies", null, "NoiId", NoiId)]
        public String Species{ get; set; }
        ...
```

And what I want is for the UIHint("Species") to take a dynamic value for NoiId from this VO.  You see I've attempted this.

However this doesn't work and from what I've read UIHints can only take static values.

What mechanism can I use to achieve this so that I can pass the value of NoiId in?

Comment: I believe what we have as ViewObjects (VO) are ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates.  I found http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html which may lead me to what I'm trying to achieve ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about it in the wrong way.  Which often happens when you work with frameworks that do lots of magic under-the-hood.

I fixed it by adding a `.Data(javascript_function)` to `the_template` specified in `UIHint(the_template)`.  The_Template being `NlsSubSpecies.ascx`:

```
<%:
    Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlNlsSubSpecies")
           .DataTextField("Text")
           .DataValueField("Value")
           .DataSource(source =>
           {
               source.Read(read =>
               {
                   read.Action("GetNLSSubSpecies", "RefData").Data("getSpecies");
               });
           })
           .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("setDefaultValue"))
%>
```

And in the relevant `.ascx` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSpecies() {
        let species = { species: '<%=Model.SpeciesCode%>' };
        return species;
    }
</script>
```

And in the `RefDataController.cs`:

```
public JsonResult GetNLSSubSpecies(String species)
{
    ...
```

And finally (or firstly), (in) the ViewObject / template:

```
[DataMember, UIHint("NlsSubSpecies")]
public String Species{ get; set; }
```